# awk command to combine multiple parameters

Tags: hadoop, awk, hdfs

I am *attempting* to write an awk command and am having some difficulty.  My task is to obtain a list of files in an hdfs directory, then copy each file to a target directory.  So far I have this:

```
hls $files_v | grep $rdir | awk '{print "hdfs dfs -cp "$NF}'
```

- hls is simply an alias to "hdfs dfs -ls"
- $files_v is my Source Directory
- $rdir is a hadoop partition by date string, 2019-01-09 in this case

I need to combine what I have so far with my Target Directory so I end up with multiple lines which read "hdfs dfs cp /some/source/file /some/target/directory/path.

I have still another variable, $tgt_dir" which contains the specific directory I want to copy TO and do not understand how to include this in my awk commands.

The reason I have so many variables is because I will be using multiple values for Source directory, partition date, and Target Directory. I decided it was easier to re-define each variable and re-use them in my script. I defined each as run-time parameters like $1, $2, etc and can update variable at runtime this way.

Thank you!

Comment: Question is not clear and too broad: 1) please show example source dir structure 2) what is `$rdir` 3) what is the expected output / operation. What is the specific issue?

Comment: I defined "$rdir" in my original post.  Yes, you're right, I never asked a specific question.  I should have asked "how do I pass multiple variables to awk, combining them into one output statement".  Or something close to that, anyway.

Thank you for pointing out the shortcoming(s) of my post; this will help me be more clear in the future!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
files_v=/the/source/path
rdir=2019-01-09
tgt_dir=/the/target/path
hls $files_v | grep $rdir | awk -v tgt_dir=$tgt_dir '{print "hdfs dfs -cp",$NF,tgt_dir}'
```

BTW, why don't you just usethe following?

```
hdfs dfs -cp /the/source/path/2019/01-09/* /the/target/path/.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!  The solution you provided worked perfectly.

The reason I don't want to use your 2nd suggestion is because my Source Dir is the path "/archive/abcxyz_dir" under which are MANY files of different types and dates.  I need to identify both the specific files as well as certain dates of those files, all in 1 directory.  So I need some flexibility in my Source Path, Dates, and Target Path.

Does that make sense?